# Filling stacked/dodged bar with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I'm trying to build a chart combining stacked and dodged to compare two business lines over months on two different KPIs (VOL and NV).
I would have something like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/groCS.jpg)

I would use 4 different colours but even using the

```
scale_fill_manual
```

it uses just the first two for all the categories.
Do you think it is possible? Otherwise I don't go further adjusting other details

Thanks

Bruno

this is result I'm stucked with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/874ir.jpg

```
df=data.frame(
  SOC=rep(c("ENERGIA","ENERGIE"),each=4),
  MESE_RIF=rep(c("2019_01","2019_02")),
  CHURN_TYPE=rep(c("VOL","NV"),each=2),
  CHURN_RATE=rep(c(1.35,1.14,0.23,0.22,1.49,1.54,0.13,0.10)),
  NR_LOST=rep(c(8288,7010,1432,1372,2818,2857,247,186)))

#filling colors
fill <- c("#72A3C9", "#B9DDF1","#F07E27","#FFC786")


#graph
ggplot(df, aes(x = SOC, y = CHURN_RATE, fill = CHURN_TYPE)) + 
geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + facet_wrap( ~ MESE_RIF)  + 
geom_text(data=df, aes(label = (df$NR_LOST)), size=4, 
position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + scale_fill_manual(values=fill)
```

Comment: So you want `ENERGIA` and `ENERGIE` to use different colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four fill colors, and `fill` is being mapped to `CHURN_RATE`, which has two values.

One approach could be to map `fill` to the combination of `CHURN_RATE` and `SOC`, like this.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = SOC, y = CHURN_RATE, 
               fill = interaction(CHURN_TYPE, SOC))) + 
...
```

[image]